# C# - Convert R Data Frame to Deedle.Frame

Tags: c#, r, deedle, r.net

I have a C# application which needs a Deedle Frame as input data. I also have a R script that return a data frame, and I don't want to re-implement the algorithm in R script by C#.
I tried using R.Net, I can get the data frame from R script in C# application, but its type is RDotNet.DataFrame.
Is there any to convert RDotNet.DataFrame to Deedle Frame in C# code?

I am also thinking about creating a F# dll library that calls the R script, then use that dll library in C# code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Deedle from F#, then you can also use the R type provider. The two are nicely integrated and you can call R from F# and get back a Deedle data frame. There is [a good example on this in the Deedle documentation](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/rinterop.html).

R provider will automatically turn R data frames into Deedle frames. For example:

```
open RProvider.datasets

// Get mtcars as a typed Deedle frame
let mtcars : Frame<string, string> = R.mtcars.GetValue()
```

The source code that does the conversion in R provider and Deedle is available too. So if you wanted to use it directly, the place to start is the `tryCreateFrame` function [in Deedle source code](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle.RProvider.Plugin/Convertors.fs#L103).

This is not really exposed to C# at this point, but we would certainly welcome a pull request making this possible for Deedle :-).

Comment: I can use F# to get the Frame returned by R script now. 
But how to send a Deedle Frame to the R script. I want to build an app that receive and Deedle Frame as input data, do something data processing, then return a Deedle Frame as the output data

Comment: This should work automatically with R provider too. Whenever you pass Deedle frame to a function exported by R provider, it will be automatically converted to R frame. See: http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/rinterop.html#From-Deedle-to-R

Comment: When I run this line of code `R.assign("dataframe", frame) `, _frame_ is a Deedle.Frame, i see that it also print the data frame to console screen. But when I run this `R.assign("text",text)`, _text_ is a text string, it doesn't print anything. And `let frame : Frame<int,string> = result.GetValue()`, this line of code also prints the data.
So I think the converter between Deedle.Frame and R Frame does print the data. 
Is there any way to avoid it?